# Windows Autorun for an HTML file

Tags: windows, autorun, inf

I have a html file on a flash drive that I would like to autorun in Windows. I have found examples of multiple ways to do this but none of them are working for me. Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

This is my latest Attempt:

```
[autorun]

icon=data/favicon.ico

label=My Project

open=ShellRun.exe OPEN-ME.htm
```

This was another attempt:

```
[autorun]
icon=data/favicon.ico
label=My Project
shellexecute=OPEN-ME.html

shell\openme=Learn More About My Project
shell\openme\command=OPEN-ME.html

shell=openme
```

Some of this is working, like the icon and the label. Just not the auto run.

Comment: I was naming my file "autorun.inf"

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use VBScript or JScript:

- test.vbs (VBScript):

  ```
  Call WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("OPEN-ME.html", 1)
  ```
- test.js (JScript):

  ```
  WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("OPEN-ME.html", 1)
  ```

Either way, it should do what you want as far as I'm aware.

Edit: By the way, ShellRun.exe is most likely a program bundled with a piece of software known as [ShellRun](http://www.phdcc.com/shellrun/) rather than a built-in Windows command.  The idea is that you can use the executable in your AutoRun file to launch an arbitrary file.

Comment: Would the files need to be named anything specific. I tried autorun.vbs and autorun.js and couldn't get them to work.

Comment: No, there shouldn't be any specific file names.  Try `wscript.exe autorun.vbs` or `wscript.exe autorun.js`.  Also make sure you didn't disable your AutoRun/AutoPlay functionality (when you insert an installation disc that you own into your disc drive, does Windows automatically launch the setup program or the application that it installs?  Most do.