# How to use autorun in Windows 7 from a Flash drive to open a webpage?

Tags: windows-7, autorun

I've been trying to come up with a way to autorun a series of HTML pages that are hosted on a USB Flash Drive. These are all static pages, and are all linked to index.html in my flash drive's root.

I tried setting up an autorun.inf file like this:

```
[autorun]
open=index.html
```

I have also tried this:

```
[autorun]
shellexecute=index.html
```

And I have tried this:

```
[autorun]
open=wscript.exe autorun.vbs
```

where autorun.vbs looks like this:

```
Call WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("index.html", 1)
```

So far, I've had no luck in getting the application to even show up on the autorun dialog. I even had a more robust autorun.inf similar to this one:

```
[autorun]
shellexecute=index.html
label=Test Application
action=Start Test Application
shell\start=Start Application
shell\start\command=index.html
shell=start
```

I switched out various shellexecute/open commands in a number of different configurations. I then stumbled upon a page during my research that said "Windows 7 no longer supports autorun.inf from flash drives." but there was no other information about this that I could find.

Anyone have a solution? I only would like to insert the flash drive and have the webpage within opened without other user input. If I have to deal with an autoplay dialog that has a "Display page" button, that would also be fine.

Edit: I also tried this link: [Windows Autorun for an HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900867/windows-autorun-for-an-html-file) but it did not work either.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in my comment, windows no longer allows this. Here is a previous Stack Overflow article:

[Auto-Running a program from USB flash drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304382/auto-running-a-program-from-usb-flash-drive)

and another one:

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/autorun-inf-does-not-work-in-windows-7-anymore/

To allow autoplay edit your settings here:

Control Panel->All Control Panel Items->AutoPlay

Comment: No. It is just a plain, recently formatted USB drive from a random company. The autorun dialog pops up, but nothing is on there except opening the file to view folders and something about speeding up my system.

Comment: I believe this was a security change by Windows from preventing viruses and the like.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to set up a bypass on a per-drive or per-computer basis? Looks like it isn't possible anymore. I find it funny that they disable autorun on usb drives, but not on cd/dvd media.

Comment: It might work under mixed content, although I'm not sure. You might have to put your site on some sort of alternative media such as a dvd.

Answer (score 0):

[This link at Microsoft](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/autoplay-not-working-for-usb-flash-drive/304f3ddd-13a1-44a9-be5a-1e9f4c74b3a9) *might* solve your problem. Their solution copied below in case of link rot:

---

**I would suggest you to use any of the below mentioned method and check if you are able to use the AutoPlay feature for removable drives as USB.**

1. Click Start and in the Search box, type gpedit.msc and press Enter.
2. Now browse to Computer Configuration\ Administrative Templates\
   Windows Components\ Autoplay Policies\ Turn off Autoplay.
3. Change the value of Turn off Autoplay to **disabled**.

You may refer to the below links for further assistance -
Change AutoPlay settings - http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Change-AutoPlay-settings
Troubleshoot AutoPlay problems - http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Troubleshoot-AutoPlay-problems

---

Good luck!

Comment: By the way: copied verbatim. Please consider all typos and grammatical errors between the horizontal lines as marked '(sic)'. :)