# Autorun.inf file not lunching the exe on Windows 7 environment

Tags: windows, autorun

I am writing code for autorun.inf file such as

```
[autorun]
open=Viewer\viewer.exe
icon=Viewer\viewer.exe,1
```

.exe is inside the Viewer Folder but i want to run or lunch this exe automatically (as Autoplay) whenever user insert CD/DVD inside the CD/DVD Drive.

But actually this is not working. I dont know why?

OS: Windows 7 (32 Bit)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use autorun in Windows 7 from a Flash drive to open a webpage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743322/how-to-use-autorun-in-windows-7-from-a-flash-drive-to-open-a-webpage)

Comment: @DavidHancock I am not lunching any web page i am trying to lunch the exe file using .inf file.

Comment: I know, I believe the linked answer points to the fact that Microsoft disabled autorun.inf in Windows 7

Comment: @DavidHancock But I am trying some sample exe with inf file that run automatically when i insert CD/DVD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this answer just using single line

```
[autorun]
open=Viewer\viewer.exe
action=Start ShellRun-CD // this line is important
```

Answer (score 2):

In relation to the above mentioned question...

```
[autorun]
open=Viewer\viewer.exe
icon=Viewer\viewer.exe,1
action=Start ShellRun-CD // this line is important
```

The 1st line after the [autorun] tells the autoplay what file to execute.
The 2nd line after the [autorun] displays the icon. If it is a DLL or EXE file then the optional position may be given. If it is an icon (.ico) file then not necessary.
The 3rd line is the description that will appear when the autoplay dialogue appears. This line is not important and does not affect the execution of the program.

Comment: In your notes, you say the third is *NOT* important, but the comment in the code block it *IS* important.