# Test Whether Employees Will Use Unknown USB Drive

Tags: usb-drive

Because of the possibilities of delivering mal-ware through usb drives (like stuxnet), my company wants to test whether or not employees will put unknown usb drives into their computers.

The idea is that we could drop a few drives around our company, and the thumb drive could e-mail the IT manager, allowing them to assess how big of a problem this is for us.

This task has fallen to me. Although I have experience in programming, this is new territory for me.

Currently: I have a program (.exe file) which will e-mail me when it is executed. It sends me the log-in name of the currently signed-in Windows user.

Problem: Once on a USB drive, there appears to be no way to automatically run it.  The best I can tell is that auto-run features were removed or patched-away once some of these exploits began happening.

Is there another approach I should be using? Or is there a way to develop this that I don't see?

Comment: This seems more like a task for a system administrator than a programmer. On most operating system, connects and disconnects of USB devices are logged somewhere. What operating system is your organization using primarily?

Comment: Almost exclusively Windows, but possibly a variety of different versions (XP, Vista, or 7 predominantly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say the payload is an EXE file, so I will assume a Windows environment.

Windows [AutoRun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoRun#Windows_Server_2003.2C_Windows_XP.2C_and_Windows_2000) is still supported.  Depending on its implementation, the user may be presented with an AutoPlay dialog, giving them choices.  Unless they click on your executable, you may not receive email.

On most windows a USB insertion will generate [System log Event 7036](https://superuser.com/questions/219401/starting-scheduled-task-by-detecting-connection-of-usb-device). With some additional logic and filtering, assuming the users are on a Windows domain, you could potentially see these events in their system logs.

Comment: This sounds promising. To make sure I understand - the user's machine will generate the log entry, and as an admin I could use PowerShell to filter through the logs across the domain and find the appropriate entries?

Comment: @indigochild Likely yes, but we are software developers, not system administrators. Ask on https://serverfault.com for details (no idea who had the idea to migrate this question to stackoverflow).

Comment: This ended up being the best solution for our case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the autorun feature anymore as of Windows 7 for exactly the reason you're worried about.

See: [How to use autorun in Windows 7 from a Flash drive to open a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743322/how-to-use-autorun-in-windows-7-from-a-flash-drive-to-open-a-webpage)

Unfortunately this doesn't mean that USB sticks are invulnerable to spreading malware.  You may have heard of [BadUSB](http://mashable.com/2014/10/03/bad-usb/#Ji3ktgaMIEq5), which can't be easily protected against.

Instead of relying on autorun.inf, (which no longer works), try putting a file inside the USB stick labeled "Read me if found.txt" and inside the file listing a place to return the USB stick along with an offer of a $10 reward.  Most people will jump at the chance for $10.  Be honest and give them the $10.

Comment: *"Be honest and give them the $10"*... and then fire them for violating the IT security policies?

Comment: @Philipp If you want to make enemies really really fast, and have the entire company completely distrust you, this is a good approach to attain that.

Comment: @Philipp Assuming this is against your IT policies. At many companies, it would not be.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be moving back to security, instead of development. This is a common [pentesting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penetration_test) task - drop a few USB devices, and see where they end up.

As you pointed out, there is a problem with using actual USB thumbdrives - how do you know that they were used? And, there's also the risk of accidentally spreading malware if one is inserted into a machine that's infected.

Many pentesters turn to a device such as the [USB Rubber Ducky](https://hakshop.myshopify.com/products/usb-rubber-ducky-deluxe?), something that looks like a thumbdrive, but actually behaves as a keyboard, running its payload when inserted. There are a number of options here; this is actually one of the demos that we used to demonstrate how to modify USB firmware ([BadUSB](https://github.com/adamcaudill/Psychson#running-demo-1-hid-payload)).

By using something that looks like a thumbdrive, but has a programmable payload, you can gather more information, and have more control.

I know a number of people that have ordered thumbdrives with custom printed cases, with the company logo - to help instill confidence - then replaced the board inside it with a Rubber Ducky; the devices were then distributed through the building and parking lot. It's an extremely effective tactic to test employee training.